# can i install azure SDK 2.1 for VS2010 after installing azure SDK 2.1 VS2012?

Tags: azure

I have installed azure SDK 2.1 for vs2012 on windows server 2012. Can I now install azure SDK 2.1 for VS2010 SP1? will azure SDK 2.1 works for both VS2012 and VS2010?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can and yes, it will work.

The VS2010 and VS2012 installations both install the SDK on your machine, but the different setups register the SDK on the different versions of Visual Studio.